# How do I update a property with the current date in a Mongoose schema on every save?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

In my database collections, I want to update a 'lastChanged' field every time the record is updated with the current datetime. I want it to be in the same format as mongoose's default date like:

`ISODate("2011-10-06T14: 01: 31.106Z")`

Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 28):

If you just want an ISO String use:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this answers the question. The question was not, "how do I create an ISO string".

Comment: This is how you create a valid ISO string to insert into Mongo.

Answer (score 17):

One way of accomplishing this is to use [Mongoose Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and update the field pre-save.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//schema
var SomethingSchema = new Schema({
  text: {type: String},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

//middle ware in serial
SomethingSchema.pre('save', function preSave(next){
  var something = this;
  something.updatedAt(Date.now());
  next();
});
```

It seems, however, that the middleware is not always invoked:

> Notes on findAndUpdate()
>
> `pre` and `post` are not called for update operations executed directly on the database, including `Model.update`,`.findByIdAndUpdate`,`.findOneAndUpdate`, `.findOneAndRemove`,and `.findByIdAndRemove`.order to utilize `pre` or `post` middleware, you should `find()` the document, and call the `init`, `validate`, `save`, or `remove` functions on the document. See [explanation](http://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/964).

**Update:** See this question "[add created_at and updated_at fields to mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669615/add-created-at-and-updated-at-fields-to-mongoose-schemas)"

Comment: You can now invoke middleware for `update` in >MongooseJS 4.0

Comment: instead of Date.now which gives system specific timestamp, you can use moment.now() from moment package which gives current time based on your timezone

Answer (score 11):

In a few days Mongo is going to announce new 2.6 version (currently you can download experimental 2.5.x version). Among [many other features](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#release-notes-for-mongodb-2-6-development-series-2-5-x) you can use [$currentDate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate) which is going to do exactly the thing you want:

```
db.users.update( 
  <criteria>,
  {
     $currentDate: { yourField: true},
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The middleware function is a good approach, however, it should be

```
SomethingSchema.pre('save', function preSave(next){
  var something = this;
  something.updatedAt = Date.now();
  next();
});
```

Since something.updateAt is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I added **updated: new Date** to fix a similar problem. Here is how I used it.

```
update: (req, res) => {
        let userId = req.params.id;
        let userParams = {
            name: {
                first: req.body.first,
                last: req.body.last
            },
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            updated: new Date
        };

        db.User.findOneAndUpdate(userId, { $set: userParams })
            .then(upUser => res.json(`Profile Updated for: ${upUser.fullName}`))
            .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    }
```