# How to have a Mongoose model field populate programatically?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema:

```
const geoframeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  count: Number,
  createdBy: String,
  polygons: [
    {
      points: [{ lat: Number, lng: Number }],
    },
  ],
});
```

I'd like to somehow have another field, `createdAt`, which populates using `doc._id.getTimestamp()`. That way I don't have to inject that value every time a user queries this collection. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669615/add-created-at-and-updated-at-fields-to-mongoose-schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pre-save hook:

```
const geoframeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    count: Number,
    createdBy: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    polygons: [
        {
            points: [{ lat: Number, lng: Number }],
        },
    ],
});

geoframeSchema.pre('save', function() {
    this.createdAt = doc._id.getTimestamp();
});
```

You'd have to make sure that doc._id.getTimestamp() is accessible from the schema or set it up as an instance method:

```
geoframeSchema.methods.getTimestamp = function() {
    ...
}
```

...and then call it in your pre-save hook:

```
geoframeSchema.pre('save', function() {
    this.createdAt = this.getTimestamp();
});
```

In this case you could also use the schema options object to set up time stamps which will populate automatically:

```
const geoframeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    count: Number,
    createdBy: String,
    polygons: [
        {
            points: [{ lat: Number, lng: Number }],
        },
    ],
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'createdAt',
        updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
    }
});
```

You can name your timestamps like so:

```
createdAt: 'timestampName'
```

Comment: Timestamps, built in! Didn't even realize that..thanks!