# How to save UTC date in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save UTC date at `mongodb` after executing an API.
**For example**, the code below at mongoose makes UTC date automatically with default option. and The saving result is '2019-05-05 02:06:03.797Z'.

```
 createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
```

And the mongoose schema has a variable as the type of Date.
And I want to put the date like `'default:Date.now'` for saving UTC after executing an API with same format.

```
recentAccess: Date,
```

Could you help me some advice?

Comment: Mongodb by default saves time in UTC. You do not need to worry about that.

Comment: But how can I update default Date.now at mongodb? I m thinking it needs using insert Date inside of 'recentAccess' after every running of a specificg API.

Comment: Allow option for [`timestamp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669615/add-created-at-and-updated-at-fields-to-mongoose-schemas). It will always give you `updatedAt` field when ever document will update.