# Always getting same timestamp - createdOn for different new entires in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, date

Below is my mongoose Schema out of which createdOn is of type date and default to Date.now().

```js
const SurveyResponseModel = mongoose.Schema({
  surveyId: { type: String, required: true },
  surveyData: [surveyData],
  result : [respResult],
  patientId: { type: String },
  surveyBy: {type: String},
  createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
});
```

Here is how I'm adding new entries to the db.

```js
const newSurvey = new surveyResponseModel({ surveyId, surveyData, surveyBy, patientId, result })
    let savedSurvey = await newSurvey.save();
```

Up until here everything works fine. The problem starts when new entries are made into the schema. I get the same timestamp of createdOn for each new entries.
What am I doing wrong? Is it `createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }` a issue or something else. Is it a problem with MongoDB or my node express server? Some help and feedback would really be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, but why don't try this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669615/add-created-at-and-updated-at-fields-to-mongoose-schemas

Comment: Thanks. I got it solved by using andys answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this code is executed (at server startup), `Date.now()` is executed and the result is saved in the object literal, hence that single timestamp will be used for the duration of the server's life.

Try passing the function instead of a value it returns at a single point in time. Mongoose will then call it at runtime.

```
createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

Comment: Thanks @andy it worked. I never knew this `Date.now()` will make difference.