# Mongoose: unable to update date typed document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i want to update a date typed document to current date. 
My schema is

```
var appEventActivity = mongoose.Schema({
                    app_key : String,
                    e_id:String,//event id from appEvent
                    u_imei:String,//user imei from appUsers
                    startAt:{type: Date, default : Date.now()},
                    endAt:{type: Date, default : Date.now()}
                });
```

and my updated part of code is

```
AppEventActivity.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.update_event_id},{$currentDate : {endAt:true}}, function(err,data){
            if(err)console.log(err);
            res.send(data);

        });
```

i have seen 
[add created_at and updated_at fields to mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669615/add-created-at-and-updated-at-fields-to-mongoose-schemas) and [How do I update a property with the current date in a Mongoose schema on every save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675549/how-do-i-update-a-property-with-the-current-date-in-a-mongoose-schema-on-every-s) but didn't get success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see here is the omission of `{ "new": true }` in order to return the modified document:

```
AppEventActivity.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "_id": req.update_event_id },
   { "$currentDate" : { "endAt": true} },
   { "new": true },
   function(err,data){
      if(err)console.log(err);
      res.send(data);
  });
```

Without `{ "new": true }` the document returned is the "un-modified" version "before" the update. Setting it shows the update you just performed.

This is a legacy pattern consistent with the MongoDB driver default behavior.

The [**`$currentDate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator of MongoDB otherwise works as expected. Here is a complete listing:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose')
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String,
  "date": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema, 'test' );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "name": "me" },
        { "$currentDate": { "date": true } },
        { "new": true, "upsert": true  },
        function(err,doc) {
          console.log(doc);
          callback(err);
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

With the output:

```
{ _id: 55e45ba528f7d03a06a2dd6e,
  name: 'me',
  __v: 0,
  date: Mon Aug 31 2015 23:50:29 GMT+1000 (AEST) }
```

So a new date was set on the server operation as opposed to on the client, which is what you are after.