# MongoDb automatically update data after a specified number of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have an MongoDb Object like

```
{
  "_id": 1.
  "updateAfter":"2021-06-28T03:31:53.000Z",
  "isPassed": false
}
```

I want to update the `"isPassed": true` after the specified time `"updateAfter"`.

Lets say the current time is 29 May 12:30 pm. The `updateAfter : 30 May 10: 50 am`. I am trying to `isPassed: true` when the current time is over the 30 May(Or greater than the current time).

Is this possible with the MongoDB `TTL indexing` process or any another idea like `time scheduler` process?

How can i do this?

#### Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use aggregation `update()`

```
 db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      isPassed: {
        $gte: [
          "$updateAfter",
          {
            $toString: new Date()
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongodb](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pk80g0AWOnf)**

Comment: Here, Did you mean aggregation as a aggregation framework or not?

Comment: Yes, you can refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Can i use myModel.findOneAndUpdate({}) without only update?

Comment: Where i use "isPassed: true" in your query?

Comment: Yes. But you use "2021-07-28T03:31:53.000Z" is it the current time? My query have to check the current time(the running time or machine time) is greater than the "updateAfter" time.

Comment: So you can easily pass `new Date()`, no?. I dont know about mongoose

Comment: Basically new Date is a current date. But i am trying to say, i am checking the time between "updateAfter" and the current machine time. You checking between two fixed value.But i want to query with time limit value.Basically when the current time will be greater than the "updateAfter", then "isPassed: true".

Comment: Because after starting the server or the mongoDb queary, the variable new Date() won't update. So, How can i check that the current time is greater than the  "updateAfter" time?

Comment: No, what I try to say if You can pass the current datetime into  `$gte: [ "$updateAfter", // set the date time here ]` sometimes this might help to get the curret date [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675549/how-do-i-update-a-property-with-the-current-date-in-a-mongoose-schema-on-every-s/9056645]

Comment: You need to pass the current date time into the query

Comment: When i pushing new Date(). It dose not update after. So how do i check the current time is greater than the "updateAfter" time. Can i use seTimeOut or setInterval types functionality in MongoDb?

Comment: I think that i can not properly explain the problem with you.Lets say the current time is 29 May 12:30 pm. The "updateAfter : 30 May  10: 50 am".  This is always true cause "updateAfter"  is always greater when we push the data into database. But i am trying to "isPassed: true" when the current time is over the 30 May(Or greater than the current time).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233070/discussion-between-varman-and-mijanur-rahman).